# SSIS: Deployment strategy

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis

In Enterprise Manager 2000 I could create a DTS Package and define a local connection.  This made it very easy to use the Pkg across dev, stage, live servers because i did not have to redefine connections.  Is there a way to do this in BIDS 2008.  I have been looking but can find no way to do this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple way I use is to have the connectionstring property of the connection as an Expression.

This expression is built up from one or more variables. The variables can then be passed in via the SQL Server Agent job step (Set Values tab). This means you can set the required values on each environment.

Other approaches are to use Windows Environment Variables, or .config files.

I use the passed-in variables approach as I have packages calling packages, and the Job Step is told the local connections for that environment, it can then pass those down to it's child packages for them to use.

Answer (score 0):

The process is slightly more complicated. I would suggest following this tutorial (which takes you step by step through creating a deploy-able SSIS package):

[Tutorial: Deploying Packages (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms365338.aspx)